# Splitting a string into groups of up to 3 numbers, or one letter and up to 3 numbers

Tags: c#, strings, parsing, .net

There was an interesting idea brought up in The 2nd Monitor where one of our regulars was trying to split a bunch of strings into a specific format.

The format should be similar to the following:

```
A000
A00
900
90
```

Where `A` is any alphabetical letter, `0` is any number, and `9` is any number `1-9`. No result string should begin with `0`, it should always begin with `A-Z` or `1-9`, and all alphabet characters will **always** be capitalized.

The input comes in a format similar to any of the following:

```
Input         | Result
900A000       | 900, A000
900900        | 900, 900
90            | 90
99099         | 990, 99
A009A09       | A009, A09
A009A09900    | A009, A09, 900
A0990A09900   | A09, 90, A09, 900
A099090A09900 | A09, 90, 90, A09, 900
A09A990       | A09, A990
A990          | A990
```

The input will *always* parse to a valid group of strings.

The method:

```
public List<string> SpecialSplit(string input)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    var currentString = new StringBuilder(4);
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = input[i];

        if (currentString.Length > 0)
        {
            // Determine whether we're at constraints or not.
            var firstCharLetter = currentString[0] >= 'A' && currentString[0] <= 'Z';
            var atMaxLetterLength = firstCharLetter && currentString.Length == 4;
            var atMaxNumberLength = !firstCharLetter && currentString.Length == 3;

            // Split if at max letter/number length, or if we're on a letter.
            var mustSplit = atMaxLetterLength || atMaxNumberLength || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';

            if (mustSplit)
            {
                // If we must split our string, then verify we're not leaving an orphaned '0'.
                if (c == '0')
                {
                    // Go back a letter, take it out of the new string, and set our `c` to it.
                    i--;
                    currentString.Length--;
                    c = input[i];
                }

                // Add and clear the string to our result.
                result.Add(currentString.ToString());
                currentString.Clear();
            }
        }

        // Add our `c` to the string.
        currentString.Append(c);
    }

    // Add our string to the result.
    result.Add(currentString.ToString());

    return result;
}
```

And the test code:

```
var tests = new string[] {
    "909A999",
    "909999",
    "90",
    "99099",
    "A009A09",
    "A009A09900",
    "A0990A09900",
    "A099090A09900",
    "A09A990",
    "A990"
};

var resultStrings = new List<string>();

foreach (var test in tests)
{
    var split = SpecialSplit(test);
    Console.WriteLine(test + ": {" + string.Join(", ", split) + "}");
    resultStrings.AddRange(split);
}

if (resultStrings.Any(x => x[0] == '0'))
    Console.WriteLine("Test failed");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Test passed");
```

Comment: _No result string should begin with 0, it should always begin with A-Z or 1-9_ this does not seem to work for `A0990A091900` which splits into A09, 90, A091, 900. Shouldn't the result be A0, 9, 90, A0, 9, 1, 900?

Comment: @t3chb0t No, because the string should be as long as possible, up to 3 numbers with an optional letter.

Comment: oops, the title say this ;-] tl;dr :-P sorry

Comment: @Anyone tempted to solve this with a regex: this all started with `([A-Z]?\d{2,3})+` failing to do the job =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `StringBuilder` isn't necessary if we know that the resulting string isn't exceeding `4` chars. I would go with a `char[]` instead which will be a magnitude faster if performance is a concern (which mostly is).

The following loc's are executed each iteration which is a waste of time as well.

> ```
> var firstCharLetter = currentString[0] >= 'A' && currentString[0] <= 'Z';
> var atMaxLetterLength = firstCharLetter && currentString.Length == 4;
> var atMaxNumberLength = !firstCharLetter && currentString.Length == 3;
>
> // Split if at max letter/number length, or if we're on a letter.
> var mustSplit = atMaxLetterLength || atMaxNumberLength || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
> ```

I would prefer a style which is more natural to read like using `char.IsLetter()` like t3chbot has mentioned in his answer.

---

A name like `firstCharLetter` isn't telling enough about what it is because its incomplete. `firstCharIsLetter` would be better imo.

---

The `if` condition

> ```
> if (currentString.Length > 0)
> ```

is only helpful/needed for the very first iteration and could be removed if the loop would start at `1` like so

```
currentString.Append(input[0]);
for (var i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
```

---

Parameter validation is missing for this `public` method but you wouldn't do that in production code like I know. Because of that I omitted the validation as well.

My take on this is a little bit longer but a little bit faster as well

```
public List<string> Split(string input)
{
    var results = new List<string>();
    char[] result = new char[4];
    int j = 0;
    bool hasLetter = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
    {

        char c = input[i];

        if (char.IsLetter(c))
        {
            if (j > 0)
            {
                results.Add(new string(result));
                result = new char[4];
                j = 0;
            }
            result[j++] = c;
            hasLetter = true;
            continue;
        }

        bool nextIsZero = (input[i + 1] == '0');

        if (!hasLetter)
        {

            if (!nextIsZero)
            {
                result[j++] = c;
            }
            if (j == 3)
            {
                results.Add(new string(result));
                result = new char[4];
                j = 0;
            }
            if (nextIsZero)
            {
                result[j++] = c;
            }
            continue;

        }

        if (nextIsZero && j == 3)
        {
            results.Add(new string(result));
            result = new char[4];
            j = 0;
            hasLetter = false;
        }
        result[j++] = c;

    }
    result[j++] = input[input.Length - 1];

    results.Add(new string(result));
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

right ... "tempted to solve this with a regex" doesn't quite cut it. There is a regex that [kinda sorta somewhat works](https://regex101.com/r/dJVa1o/1/), but I didn't get it to do exactly what I want.
Doesn't matter though, because I can make it do what I wanted, namely spit out the results directly as separate groups. Instead I got it to match the "last result" an:

```
private readonly Regex someNiceName = new Regex(@"^((?:[A-Z]\d|[1-9])\d{1,2})+$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public List<string> SpecialSplit(string input)
{
    if (input == "") 
    {
       return new List<string>(); // base case for recursion
    }
    var match = someNiceName.Match(input);
    string last = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var precedessors = SpecialSplit(input.Substring(0, match.Groups[1].Index));
    precedessors.Add(last);
    return precedessors;
}
```

With a bit of luck we don't actually need this mess, but can rely on `Captures` instead:

```
public List<string> SpecialSplit(string input) 
{
    var match = someNiceName.Match(input);
    var fullMatch = match.Groups[0];
    return fullMatch.Captures().Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
}
```

unfortunately I do not have C# available to check right now, but that **might** work better :)

Answer (score 4):

I like your algorithm because I think it does the splitting exacly the way it should be done.

What I like less are the comments. I find they are unnecessary if the logic is encapsulated appropriately but one explaining the `0` and why the backtracking takes place.

As the string is **always** capitalized I think it's ok to use `char.IsLetter` rather then the range `A-Z`.

With a little bit of C# 7 and its new local funcitons and the new `switch` it could look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SpecialSplit(string value)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        if (CanSplit())
        {
            Backtrack();
            yield return result.ToString();
            result.Clear();
        }
        result.Append(Current());

        char Current() => value[i];
        bool CanSplit() => result.Length > 0 && (result.Length == MaxLength() || char.IsLetter(Current()));

        void Backtrack()
        {
            // If we must split our string, then verify we're not leaving an orphaned '0'.
            if (Current() == '0')
            {
                i--;
                result.Length--;
            }
        }
    }

    if (result.Length > 0) yield return result.ToString();  

    int MaxLength()
    {
        switch (result[0])
        {
            case char c when char.IsLetter(c): return 4;
            case char c when char.IsDigit(c): return 3;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Invalid char {result[0]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, this is a nice trick `result.Length--;` :-)

Comment: Hohoho, a DV. Reason?

Comment: Don't understand the DV either.

Comment: Unintentional  DV. Just saw it now myself and wondering how it happened! Mis-click? If you can edit the answer I will undo - can't now because it happened over 2 hours ago. Really sorry about this

Comment: @AlanT edited. You're the first person I've ever met that explained a DV ;-)

Comment: Un-DVEd.  Again, sorry about the mess-up on my part.